# How to open OLE2 file format document

Tags: pdf, microsoft, document

I received a file that is .OLE2 format by email and I can't get it open.

When I try to open it with Document Viewer (default pfd program Ubuntu) it says it can't support it. I searched in the Software Center for OLE2, and it returned a program called RipOle. It says it opens that format, but you have to run it in the terminal and I don't know how.

Does any one know how to open OLE2 documents? Or do you know how to work ripole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No experience with ripole or .OLE2 documents, but from the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/ripole.1.html) it doesn't seem too hard to run from the terminal.

Have you used the terminal at all before? If not have a [quick read of this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

All I think you need to do is open a terminal then assuming the file is in /home/user/, make a new directory where you want the file to be extracted to (eg tmp) then run

```
ripole -i file.ole2 -v -d tmp
```

Just replace file.ole2 with your filename and tmp with the directory you want the contents to be extracted to.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! Worked good, albeit with a bit of a learning curve. I found an alternate solution to my own question. It was to install Adobe Reader, the official PDF reader on their website. It handled the .OLE2 file perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternate solution to my own question. It was to install Adobe Reader, the official PDF reader on their website. It handled the .OLE2 file perfectly.

Available at: http://get.adobe.com/reader/